# Is it possible to create a smart contract that makes other smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-deployment

I am wondering if I could make a smart contract that makes other smart contracts when prompted to. For example, I send a transaction to smart contract A telling it to make smart contract B. And smart contract B has my original wallet as the owner.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Check these two ([1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18936/deploying-contract-from-contract), [2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12315/gas-consuption-deploying-contracts-from-within-a-contract)) already answered questions. Hopes it helps.